# QT Not Updating Second UI

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have 2 UIs and I am trying to update one from the other. I have the classes `phone`, `user_ui`, `test_ui`, and `user_transmitter`. The `user_ui` is the one that a user can interact with such as if the user pressed the toggle button on the UI of the user_ui then the status should be displayed on the UI of the test_ui. The user_transmitter transmits the inputs and outputs and that's its only job, there is no UI to it. The phone class just contains the variables and nothing else.

---

user_ui.h:

```
#ifndef USER_UI_H
#define USER_UI_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTimer>

#include <phone.h>
#include "user_transmitter.h"
#include "test_ui.h"

using namespace std;

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class user_ui; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class user_ui : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    user_ui(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~user_ui();
    Phone phone;
    QTimer *timer;
private:
    Ui::user_ui *ui;
    user_transmitter user_t;
    void updateUI();
    void connections();
signals:
    void toggeButton(int);
private slots:
    void toggleButton1();
    void update();
};
#endif // USER_UI_H
```

user_ui.cpp:

```
#include "user_ui.h"
#include "ui_user_ui.h"

#include <QMessageBox>

user_ui::user_ui(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::user_ui)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    update();
    connections();
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));

user_ui::~user_ui()
{
    delete ui;
}

void user_ui::update()
{
    ui->status->setText((phone.status) ? "On" : "Off");
}

void user_ui::connections() {
    QObject::connect(this, &user_ui::toggleButton, &user_t, &user_transmitter::toggleButton);
    connect(ui->button, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(toggleButton1()));
}

void user_ui::toggleButton1() {
    phone.status= !phone.status;
     emit toggleButton(1);
}
```

user_transmitter.h:

```
#ifndef USER_TRANSMITTER_H
#define USER_TRANSMITTER_H

#include <vector>
#include "phone.h"
#include "test_ui.h"

class user_transmitter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit user_transmitter(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Phone phones;
public slots:
    void toggleButton(int);
private:
    void setUpSignals();
    test_ui test;
signals:
    void button(int,bool);
};

#endif // USER_TRANSMITTER_H
```

user_transmitter.cpp:

```
#include "user_transmitter.h"

user_transmitter::user_transmitter(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    setUpSignals();
}

void user_transmitter::setUpSignals(){
   QObject::connect(this, &user_transmitter::button, &test, &test_ui::button);

}

void user_transmitter::button(int index)
{
    phones.status = !phones.status;
    cout << "From transmitter: " << phones.status<< endl;
    emit button(index, phones.status);
}
```

test_ui.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_UI_H
#define TEST_UI_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class test_ui;
}

class test_ui : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit test_ui(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~test_ui();
    QTimer *timer;
public slots:
    void button(int,bool);

private:
    Ui::test_ui *ui;
signals:
};

#endif // TEST_UI_H
```

test_ui.cpp:

```
#include "test_ui.h"
#include "ui_test_ui.h"

test_ui::test_ui(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::test_ui)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

test_ui::~test_ui()
{
    delete ui;
}

void test_ui::button(int index, bool status){
    qDebug() << "From test: " << status;
    ui->status->setText((status) ? "On" : "Off");
}
```

My problem is that when I press the toggle button of user_ui's UI, the "on" or "off" status should display on the user UI and the test_ui. It displays on the user UI but not the test_ui. The qdebug line in the transmitter and the test class print but the UI of the test does not get updated so I am guessing that the function is getting called. So, I am not sure if it's a signal slot problem since the qdebug line is printing or if it's a timing problem.

I tested out my test UI by trying to print something in the QLineEdit box from a different function in that class and it works so there is no problem there.

Comment: How do you instantiate the objects (i.e. your `main.cpp` file)? I would guess the UI not updating looks like a problem with the event loop.

Comment: #include "user_ui.h"
#include "test_ui.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    user_ui user;
    test_ui test;
    user.show();
    test.show();
    return a.exec();
}

Comment: Wow, it worked! I did not have the connections in my main file. I am very new to QT so I had no idea I had to include it in there! Thank you so much, I am really thankful, I had been trying to fix this since forever.

Comment: I'm glad I could point in the right direction! Note that you can write an answer to your own question. This will help other users who have similar problems be revealing that this question is actually answered.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by simply adding my Signal and Slot connections from the 2 classes (user_ui & user_transmitter) to my main.cpp.